# Why is this variable not being set?

Tags: c, microcontroller, long-integer, volatile

I am working on a piece of code that computes some values based on timing data. It is running on a microcontroller (TI MSP430)

I am getting unusual behavior in that a variable never seems to get its value assigned.

```
unsigned int angle = 0;
unsigned long int average_period;
void main(void){
    ...
    while (1){
        ....
        angle = ((2359325536UL)/average_period);
        ...
        }
    }
```

In this code I have a global variable angle (it needs to be global as it is accessed in interrupts) and it calculated and set repeatedly in the main loop of my program.

However its value never changes, If I set angle to some other arbitrary value, it stays as that value so its not like the calculation is outputting zero.

If I make angle volatile it works correctly although my code size doubles from (3kB to 7.5kB). What would be causing this and can it be avoided without using the volatile keyword.

Note:I am not that familiar with the volatile keyword beyond that it can be used to prevent unused variables from being optimized out.

Comment: shouldn't angle be defined as an `unsigned long`?

Comment: The resulting value will be in the range of around 0-36000 and where it is used elsewhere is with unsigned integers. It was my understanding these could be converted implicitly.

Comment: this is exactly what volatile for. without it, the loop can be optimized away

Comment: How is `average_period` set?

Comment: Why can it be optimized away, there are other values computed in a similar fashion within the loop and angle is made used of in other interrupts in the code.

Comment: Average_period is set calculated higher up in the while loop and is effectively a IIR filter of a timer value. It is being calculated and set correctly.

Comment: The TI compiler has an option called 'keep generated assembly'.  See [this TI support thread](http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/70365.aspx). This will let you figure out exactly what the compiler did with that variable.

Comment: Your code is accessing the same variable from more than one execution path (main and an interrupt) therefore, it must be 'protected' using a semaphore (or similar) mechanism.  Without that protection, there is no guarantee that the interrupt is reading what main is writing.

Comment: If that is the case then why has this never become and issue with any other variable accessed the in a similar way.

In addition most example code will make use of globals in this way.

Comment: user3.6e6 has oversimplified. Single int access is safe.  Where you would need protection is if you are setting a pair of related variables like `angle` and `distance` together in the main loop and expecting the ISR to always be acting on a matching pair.  Unless you force some synchronization, there is no guarantee the ISR won't run after setting `angle` but before `distance`.

Answer (score 4):

Usually `volatile` is used to signal that a variable can change outside the normal control flow, for example in an ISR.   But it sounds like you are only reading `angle` in ISRs, not setting it.

So my guess is that  `angle` is never used outside the `while (1)` loop, and the optimizer is assuming that its value doesn't matter, so it skips the assignment.  `volatile` tells it that it can't make any such assumptions.

To avoid volatile, try using `angle` outside the loop, or passing it to a function defined in another file, so that the compiler thinks the computed value is important.

Comment: or just use a couple of #pragma statements to turn off optimization around the setting of the 'angle' value.

Comment: "If you want to avoid using a hammer you can drive in the nail with a brick or a piece of wood."

Comment: `volatile` is the wrong tool for the job.  The OP needs to signal to the compiler that the value of `angle` set in the main loop is used elsewhere, and can't be optimized out.  `volatile` doesn't say that, it says that `angle` can change in ways unexpected to the compiler.
As the OP says, that forces defensive code generation and 2X the code.  Every single access will get an additional 'load' instruction, even back-to-back lines in the same ISR.  If this code is only setting vars in the background loop and reading in ISRs, those extra loads are completely unneeded, and may harm timing.